# How Young inequality was applied?

Tags: functional-analysis, finite-element-method, galerkin-methods

Let $|\cdot|$ a norm in $L^2$ and $\|\cdot\|$ a norm in $H_0^1$. Then

$\begin{align}
&|u_h^n|^2 + 2 \theta \Delta t h^{-1} |u_h^n|\|u_h^{n+\theta}\| |u_h^{n+ \theta} - u_h^n| +2 \theta \Delta t |f^n| \|u_h^{n+\theta}\| + 2 \theta \Delta t |g^n|_{L^\infty}  \|u_h^{n+\theta}\| \\
& \leq |u_h^n|^2 + \nu \theta \Delta t \|u_h^{n+\theta}\|^2 + \frac{1}{2}|u_h^{n+\theta}-u_h^n|^2 + C_0(\Delta t h^{-1})^2 |u_h^n|^2 \|u_h^n\|^2 + \frac{C_o \Delta t}{\nu}(|f^n|^2 + |g|^2_{L^\infty}).
\end{align}
$
where $\theta, \nu, h, \Delta t >0.$

I'm struggling with second side of this inequality, and i don't know how article reached it.

I found this expression to second side, 
$$|u_h^n|^2 + \frac{1}{2}|u_h^{n+\theta} - u_h^n|^2 +2(\theta h^{-1} \Delta t)^2|u_h^n| \|u_h^n\|^2 + \nu \| u_h^{n+\theta}\|^2 + \frac{2(\theta \Delta t)^2}{\nu}(|g^n|^2_{L^\infty} + |f^n|^2), $$
in this case $C_0 = 2\theta ^2.$

This is in article http://www.math.ualberta.ca/ijnam/Volume-7-2010/No-4-10/2010-04-12.pdf where i found this.
How could i apply Young inequality to achieve which this article got?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The left-hand side is
$$L=|u_h^n|^2+I_1+I_2+I_3,$$
where, by [Young's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%27s_inequality_for_products#Elementary_case),
\begin{align*}
I_1&=2 \theta \Delta t h^{-1} |u_h^n|\|u_h^{n+\theta}\| |u_h^{n+ \theta} - u_h^n|\leq
C_{\varepsilon}\left(2 \theta \Delta t h^{-1} |u_h^n|\|u_h^{n+\theta}\|\right)^2+\varepsilon|u_h^{n+ \theta} - u_h^n|^2,\\\\
I_2&=2 \theta \Delta t |f^n| \|u_h^{n+\theta}\| \leq 2 \theta \Delta t \left(C_\delta|f^n|^2+{\delta} \|u_h^{n+\theta}\|^2\right),\\\\
I_3&=2 \theta \Delta t |g^n|_{L^\infty}  \|u_h^{n+\theta}\|\leq2 \theta \Delta t \left(C_\delta|g^n|_{L^\infty}^2+{\delta} \|u_h^{n+\theta}\|^2\right).
\end{align*}

Therefore,

\begin{align*}L\leq&\;|u_h^n|^2+ C_{\varepsilon}\left(2 \theta \Delta t h^{-1} |u_h^n|\|u_h^{n+\theta}\|\right)^2+\varepsilon|u_h^{n+ \theta} - u_h^n|^2+2 \theta \Delta t \left(C_\delta|f^n|^2+{\delta} \|u_h^{n+\theta}\|^2\right)\\
&+2 \theta \Delta t \left(C_\delta|g^n|_{L^\infty}^2+{\delta} \|u_h^{n+\theta}\|^2\right)\\
=&\;|u_h^n|^2
+4{\delta} \theta \Delta t \|u_h^{n+\theta}\|^2
+\varepsilon|u_h^{n+ \theta} - u_h^n|^2
+C_{\varepsilon}4 \theta^2\left( \Delta t h^{-1}\right)^2 |u_h^n|^2\|u_h^{n+\theta}\|^2\\
&+2 \theta C_\delta \Delta t\left(|f^n|^2+|g^n|_{L^\infty}^2\right).
\end{align*}
Taking $\delta=\frac{\nu}{4}$ and $\varepsilon=\frac{1}{2}$, we obtain the desired result with $C_0=\max\{2\theta,2\theta^2\}$.